# Java Using Stream and Lambda Expressions Instead of Iterator

Tags: java, lambda, iterator, java-stream

I have an assignment for my Computer Science course and our instructor wants us to use Stream and Lambda expressions for an iterator. I haven't seen the warning and I wrote the needed code according to my own taste and here it is:

```
static List<User> getUsers(String firstName){
    Iterator<User> it = users.iterator();
    ArrayList<User> tempList = new ArrayList<User>();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        User tempUser = it.next();
        if(tempUser.getFirstName().equals(firstName)){
            tempList.add(tempUser);
        }
    }
    return tempList;
}
```

How can I turn this into a Stream & Lambda code?
Thanks so much for your answers.

Comment: If he wants you to write lambdas, then he should have explained how to write the code in general. What have you tried so far?

Comment: She had added some tutorial files and oracle doc links for both Stream and Lambda expressions to the assignment pdf but we have never seen them before in class so I read the files but I didn't understand the syntax throughly so I decided to post a question here. However Aominè and azro explained very clearly, thanks so much again.

Comment: the syntax is simple: you write version of your code as if it was anonymous class, then gradually remove the extra code so that only "essential" parts remain.

Comment: Please accept an answer if one satisfies you and deals with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole method can be reduce in one statement which don't use intermediate variable for the List :

```
static List<User> getUsers(String firstName){
   return users.stream()                                        //iterate
               .filter(u -> u.getFirstName().equals(firstName)) //keep good ones
               .collect(Collectors.toList());                   //collect them in List
}
```

- `u` in the filter method is a local variable which will represent each element of `users` list, you can name it whatever you want
- `.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` will assure you to have a ArrayList instead of `toList()` which can change later but no problem using it *There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use toCollection(Supplier)* from the doc

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! While using lambda expressions for the filter method, don't I need to declare what u is? And if I write .toList instead of .toCollection(ArrayList::new) like in the answer below, does it create an unspecified List, and if it does would it be a problem?

Comment: @TrkDgnr in addition to azro's answer. if you care about the _type_ of the list returned and whether it's a _mutable_ or _immutable_ list etc then go for `.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`. however, if that doesn't concern you then use `.toList()`. it's as simple as that.

Comment: @TrkDgnr as for _don't I need to declare what `u` is?_, you can like this `.filter((User u) -> u.getFirstName().equals(firstName)) `, but since the compiler can infer the type, you don't need to. whether you should explicitly specify the type or not is a matter of preference, thus go with whatever approach you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<User> tempUsers = users.stream()
    .filter(tempUser -> tempUser.getFirstName().equals(firstName))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
//TODO do something useful with it
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stream from the users and then perform a `filter` operation to retain all users whos name equals `firstName` and then utilize `Collectors.toCollection` to accumulate the results into an `ArrayList`.

```
List<User> tempList = users.stream()
                           .filter(e -> e.getFirstName().equals(firstName))
                           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Inside the filter method can I use more than one condition: .filter(e -> e.condition1() && e.condition2()) ?

Comment: @TrkDgnr sure you can. you can use as many conditions separated by a logical `or` or logical `and` as you want. basically any condition that is valid in an `if` statement is also valid in a `filter` operation.